# How can I capture metrics from an emulated (SNES) game?

Tags: android-emulator, emulation

My goal is to emulate a game (e.g., Super Bombliss) using an Android emulator (e.g., Snes9x EX+) and to capture game metrics (e.g., score and level) as the game is played.

I assume I would need to modify the open-source emulator and/or to modify the ROM to do this, but I need some guidance on the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer "How can I capture metrics from an emulated (SNES) game?" you need to first answer "Where can I find metrics in a SNES game?". The answer to the latter is "It depends on the game."

Think about GameShark codes, they write a value to a specific position of the memory.

- It can write a value constantly to a memory position. For keeping you life bar always full on Mortal Kombat, for example.
- It can write a value to a memory position just once. If you want to jump to last level of Sunset Riders.

But how do they know which memory position they should write to? That is the hard question. Usually it comes down to reverse engineering the ROM. You create a map of which memory position corresponds to each metric you are looking for.

Let's assume you want to find your current score and your current level on Super Mario World. A possible solution would be to constantly scan the RAM memory, looking for a known value and create a map of matches.

Knowing your score is 321, you can dump the RAM and look for where memory positions that contain 321. If only one matches, there is a very likely chance that it is the memory position that indicates your score. If you have more matches you should keep a list of all matches and keep playing until your score changes. If it changes to 567 now you check from your previous list if any of the memory positions now holds the value 567.

It is not always straight forward, for example, for the stage level 6-3. Should you look in the memory for 6 and for a 3 separately? What if the game stores the levels in just one variable represented as BCD 63. Then you would have to look for something completely different.

The only way to be sure 100% is by reverse engineering the ROM, in that way you know where the game goes fetch whatever is displayed on the screen.

Now to answer your original question "How can I capture metrics from an emulated (SNES) game?" you have to first figure out where those metrics are located in every game ROM and once you know you just need to build an emulator that listens to modifications in those memory positions so you can capture those metrics.

You can find many websites that are dedicated to reverse engineering ROMs. I suggest you take a look at the work done on http://www.romhacking.net/.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful info!